# Receiving data in a raspberry pi sent through IEEE.802.11n

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, wifi

I want to send/receive out some data from a raspberry pi using the WLAN protocol      IEEE-802.11n. I tried searching a lot but could not find any library in any language which can send/receive data sent through the ieee 802.11n protocol. My receiver is also a raspberry pi.

Basically, the sender is connected to some devices and is supposed to send out some data which is to be sent through the wifi (ieee.802.11n) to another raspberry pi. And to add to my problems how is the data sent from the sender is not known. All I know is that it is sent through the ieee.802.11n protocol.(There is a wifi dongle attached to the senders raspberry pi.)

So if someone could point me to a library or any solution as to how to read that data sent through this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to research this more so that you can ask more specific questions. I doubt any answer is worth an upvote except for the effort put in.

I'll give it a try, and hope this "puts you" in the right direction.

If you manage to setup the RPi-sender as an access point and manage to connect the RPi-receiver to that network, you are well on your way. Since [beacons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame) and [probe request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) will start being sent automagically from the sender to the receiver. From there you can start [injecting](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=inject%20packets), [injecting](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_inject.3pcap.html) or in some other way sending packets from sender to receiver. Easiest first step is of course [pinging](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) (this can go either way. sender->receiver and vice versa)

If you manage to setup an ad-hoc network, then there is no real "sender" and/or "receiver", but injecting/sending packets work the same way.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529495/how-can-i-send-raw-packets-over-wifi-without-a-network) is a similar question on SO.
Also mentioning [libraries](http://www.tcpdump.org/)